# Angular 6 data not getting binded to UI OnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-cli

I have a problem that my dynamic data is not getting binded to the UI and also Data tables. I have tried using various ways but its not working. I am using smart admin latest theme for my development of website

when I hit the api i get response.

```
var tabledata:any[]=[]
Get(){
    this.getservice().subscribe(
        res=>{
            if(res && res.data && res.data.length>0){
                this.tabledata=res.data;
                console.log(this.tabledata);
            }
        }
    )
}
```

In html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of tabledata">
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Try to pipe it with async

Comment: i tried async but didn't work

Comment: When you console.log(res), do you see anything?

Comment: yes i receive my response

Comment: Have you add *ngIf before your code to check variable "tabledata" ?

Comment: yes I have added but it still does not bind

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to excute your Get method in OnInit?
Why do your Get method starts with a capital letter?
Why do you declare your table as a table of any? Using typed objects i always better.
Can you try this code below?

```
    vartabledata: Person[];

    class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() { this.get()  
      }

    get(){
        this.getservice().subscribe(
            res=>  {this.tabledata = res.data;
                    console.log(this.tabledata);}
       )}
    }
```

In front i would suggest you to add *ngIf so you display table only when your data are loaded.

```
<div *ngIf="tabledata">
<tr *ngFor="let data of tabledata">
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

If there are no data even with this, try to do

```
<div *ngIf="tabledata">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of tabledata">
            {{data | json}}
        </tr>
    </div>
```

I think that you receive a data object that doesn't contains name and age 
 attributes